# Syntax error for virtual layer query

Tags: qgis

I have issues trying to write the query for the virtual layer. I am trying to get two layers 'trials' and 'interactions' to merge with the common fields of Longitude and latitude. However I am struggling to get it right without a syntax error occurring. Does anyone know how to correctly write it? The below is what I put

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, d."id"
FROM "Trail" AS a
JOIN "Interactions" AS d ON a."Latitude","Longitude" = d."Latitude","Longitude"
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL needs every little bit spelled out for it separately, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, d."id"
FROM "Trail" AS a
JOIN "Interactions" AS d ON a."Latitude" = d."Latitude"
      AND a."Longitude" = d."Longitude"
```

Comment: Thank you. I have entered that and now it says layer not valid. does anyone know a reason for this?

Comment: @alison Sorry Alison, not sure of the reason.  The SQL syntax is correct,  The only error I could create was by misspelling one of the layer names, but that gave the error "Referenced table in query not found" - it didn't say layer not valid.  For troubleshooting you could test query each layer separately:
 `SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM "Trail" AS a`
   and 
 `SELECT DISTINCT d."id" FROM  "Interactions" AS d`
Good luck.